# Why is the vendor File is not showing up in GoLand even though it exists?

Tags: go, goland

I am using GoLand for GO. I am using dep ensure for dependency management and this creates a vendor directory within the root project directory. This vendor directory exists and has the correct dependencies in it. However, GoLand IDE is not recognizing this directory and as a result the ide thinks that these dependencies are not in the project. However, I am able to build the project successfully because the folder exists, just not in the ide.

```
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/japplebaum/projects"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.2/libexec"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.2/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/r2/y6dlsprd6kzc76kjk01vlv8h0000gn/T/go-build291641657=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

I am expecting to see the vendor folder in the IDE. Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: Did you enable dep integration? File -> Settings -> Go -> Dep

Comment: I did not, but I just upgraded to Goland 2018.3.3 and this seems to have fixed the issue.